# Edittext disable system paste icon

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have problem with edit text while copy/paste. I know there are lots of question about this on stack-overflow,

the problem is,

```
editText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText1.setLongClickable(false);
        editText1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);


 edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

i added the code above, but i couldn't prevent android to show paste icon as you can see below link,

**image link** 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8r3th4bcg4co6fu/screenshot_2013-12-10-14-34-24.png

any feedback will be appreciated,
thanks...

Comment: Clear Project and Rebuild.

Comment: It is not about project cleaning, pls look at the image, you will understand what i mean, thanks

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Answer (score 0):

Set longClickable false for edittext on xml file

```
android:longClickable="false"
```